# How do I use address_override for addresses that are not in the U.S.?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I am using Paypal IPN to process orders on an ecommerce site. One issue I'm having is figuring out how to send address information to PayPal for the `address_override` function.

For a U.S. address it's easy. You just do something like this:

```
first_name = first
last_name = last
address1 = 1 main st
address2 = APT 304
city = Cityname
zip = 01234
state = NY
country = US
```

But for a Canadian address, for example, the state field cannot be entered and I cannot find a "Province" field to replace it.

What do I do in this situation? What about all the other countries?
The documentation list all the countries and country codes that they accept. But I see nothing on how to actually send these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, apparently the PayPal documentation is wrong. The description given for the `state` variable is:

> U.S. state
>
> For allowable values; use the Official U.S. Postal Service
>   Abbreviations.

This is incorrect. The state variable can be the abbreviation of the selected country's equivalent of a state. So if shipping to an address in Ontario you need to put `ON` in the state field.